# After clearing cache/storage, won't let us create a new profile

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

My son's Xbox's storage was full and so it deleted some things.  Trying to follow some guidance, I was advised to clear storage, which I did.  This included all profiles.  He is now trying to create a new profile and it pops up this message: "Couldn't sign in your profile.  Please try again."  He isn't trying to sign in, he is trying to create a new profile.  Any help would be awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: Does your son have an Xbox Live profile?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but +1 for a good question.

Comment: Realising you cannot comment. Try removing the HDD and powering up the console. If you have an Xbox Live profile, download it using your email and password. If you are able to, plug a blank USB into the Xbox, configure it to be Xbox360 storage and try that as an alternate.

Comment: Years later: it's not super clear from the question. Are you trying to sign into XBox live, or just make a local profile on the box? Are you connected to the network?

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me, nothing I tried worked other than restoring factory settings. Just be sure to store anything like save files onto a USB/Hard Drive first!